# Como insertar una variable de suma php en una base de datos mysql

Tags: php

En mi base de datos tengo los siguientes campos id, código producto, cantidad, precio_unitario, valor_total, mediante un formulario yo ingreso todos esos valores, se debe calcular el valor_total y esa suma debe insertarse en la base de datos, me confundo sobre como es el proceso en php que me permita hacer esa operación, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme

Comment: Tienes algo de código que hayas hecho para ver en que te equivocas?

Answer (score 1):

Si tu intención es guardar ese `valor_total` en la base de datos, en primer lugar debería ser un campo más (como `id`, `codigo_producto`, etc) en la base de datos.

Luego, cuando el usuario haga el submit del formulario, vos tendrías que capturar los datos del formulario, y en función a `cantidad` y `precio_unitario` calcular `valor_total` antes de ingresarlo en la base de datos, por ejemplo:

```
$cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
$precio_unitario = $_POST['precio_unitario'];
$valor_total = $cantidad * $precio_unitario;
```

De esta manera ya tenés el valor de `$valor_total` como para ingresarlo con el resto de los datos en la DB. Cómo vas a hacer esto último depende de si estas usando PHP nativo con `mysqli` o `PDO`, o algún framework. Pero la lógica viene por ese lado.

Comment: Estoy usando php nativo, muchas gracias por la respuesta, entonces siguiendo esa lógica, no tendría que agregar nada más en la sentencia insert???

Comment: Si, en la sentencia `INSERT` deberías poner todos los campos necesarios para hacer un insert (Todos aquellos que en la base de datos hayas marcado como `not null`). El campo `ID`, por ejemplo, si es auto-generado (`AUTO INCREMENT`) no hace falta agregarlo al INSERT. La sentencia depende mucho de como hayas creado la base de datos, así que tenés que ver vos cual es tu caso en particular.